# Round Floating Decimal to Remove Leading Zero

Tags: unix, floating-point, printf

I need to remove leading zeros for floating decimal values less than `1.00`.

**Attempted Code:**

`printf '%.*f\n' 0.12`

**Result:** `0.1`

**Expected Result:** `.1`

Comment: Which tool are you using for `printf` ?

Comment: Hi @anubhava, that was the exact command that i typed into my Ubuntu terminal

Comment: bash doesn't allow floating points. If you're using `zsh` then use `printf '%.1f\n' 0.12`